# Nodejs: mongoose skip in aggregate does not work correct

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

And I have 2 documents in my database.

So, When `$skip` is `0`, `data` return one document.

```
const data = await MyData.aggregate([
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $skip: 0 },
  ])
```

But if I change `$skip` to `1`, `data` return empty array!

```
const data = await MyData.aggregate([
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $skip: 1 },
  ])
```

And if I change `$limit` to `2`, `data` return two documents!

```
const data = await MyData.aggregate([
    { $limit: 2 },
    { $skip: 0 },
  ])
```

Comment: What's the issue here. skip/limit are working exactly as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters.

When you don't have a `$match` at the start of the pipeline, there will be an implicit collection scan that reads all the documents in the collection.

When the `{$limit: 1}` stage begins, all of the documents will be in the pipeline, when it completes, the output will be a single document, which is passed on to the next stage.

The `{$skip: 1}` stage then skips the first document, and finding nothing else, returns an empty result set.

The solution here is to skip first, then limit.

Comment: Oops! thats correct. thank you.